# Всплывающие миниатюры на jquery javascript css

Tags: jquery, изображения, javascript, html, css

Добрый день. Помогите написать такой скрипт, который делал бы превью карточки товара как [тут](http://www.bonprix.ru/kategoriya/nizhnieie-bielie-bielie-dlia-osobykh-sluchaiev-push-ap-i-s-chashiechkami-na-podkladkie/) по наведению на миниатюру.

Очень нужно сделать именно так... 
Искал подобные решения в интернете. Находил, но не то. У меня на странице будет минимум 4 превью карточки товара. А то, что я находил, годилось только на одну. Как я понимаю, нужно каким то образом каждому изображению присваивать идентификатор и обрабатывать его в скрипте js. Но как это сделать вообще не понимаю...
Очень прошу помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Собственно концепция примерно такова: http://jsfiddle.net/w5Lqt/2/

Comment: Стилистическая http://jsfiddle.net/w5Lqt/3/[поправочка].

Comment: @Crasher не работает.

Comment: [Простите](http://jsfiddle.net/y9My9/) :)

Comment: а в чем собственно смысл поправки? у меня используются делегированные события, что более правильно